# Не работает стиль скроллбара

Tags: css

Почему данный стиль скроллбара не работает в Firefox?

**Как заставить данный стиль работать в Firefox?**

```css
html::-webkit-scrollbar {
 width: 5px;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -5px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2) inset;
 -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px -5px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.2) inset;
 background-color: #f9f9fd;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
 border-radius: 10px;
 background: linear-gradient(180deg, #00c6fb, #005bea);
 -moz-background: linear-gradient(180deg, #00c6fb, #005bea);
}
```

```html
<div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

</div>
```

Comment: Сan I use говорит что никак: [-webkit-scrollbar](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-scrollbar), [-webkit-scrollbar-track](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-scrollbar-track), [-webkit-scrollbar-thumb](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-scrollbar-track)

Comment: Кто такой Сan I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только Google Chrome поддерживает псевдоэлементы `(-webkit-scrollbar, -webkit-scrollbar-track, -webkit-scrollbar-thumb)`, другими словами, стилизация полосы прокрутки работает только в Chrome, в других браузерах она работать не будет.

Comment: Неа, в yandex и opera работает норм =)